# How can one include external libraries in typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I would like to be able to create a library that is dependent on other libraries that works in both a node and in a browser environment.

**Contrived example:**

```
module Core.Libraries {
   export var lodash = require('lodash');
}
```

**Usage:**

```
var lodash = require('../../../../dist/core').Libraries.lodash;

var expect = require('chai').expect;

describe('Core.Libraries.lodash', function () {
  it('should exist', function () {
    expect(lodash).to.be.ok;
  });

  it('should be lodash', function () {
    var result = lodash([1, 2, 3])
      .map(function (i) {
        return i * 2;
      })
      .reduce(function (sum, current) {
        return sum + current;
      });

    expect(result).to.equal(12);
  });
});
```

But in the browser this does not work as it misses require. It works in node.

Comment: Have you tried to add RequireJS and compile your library with AMD? Or try some other techniques like browserify?

Answer (score 0):

> But in the browser this does not work as it misses require. It works in node.

you can use nodejs packages in the browser using browserify OR webpack. FYI Facebook uses webpack.